# how to remove/fix the warning from mail "this mail outside the organization" the access given by Google Drive API

Tags: php, email, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

```
public function shareGoogleSheet(Google_Service_Drive $service, string $email, array $role, string $spreadsheetId, string $name)
{
    $newPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
    $newPermission->setEmailAddress($email);
    $newPermission->setType(self::SHARED_TYPE);
    $newPermission->setRole($role);
    try {
        $service->permissions->create($spreadsheetId, $newPermission);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->logger->error($name . $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

The Code that's I'm using for sharing the mails. Now I configured the service account for sharing the mails...

[Warning images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXFjS.jpg)

Comment: Could you maybe add a little bit more information? It is an error or just a warning that you would like to ignore? Is the mail actually outside the organization, because then it does make a little bit of sense.

Comment: thanks for respond, it's just a warning but my client want didn't like it. let me add more info...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the problem you are facing has nothing to do with the API and more with the configuration of your domain.

Contact the administrator so he can change the settings:

- [Configure an external recipient warning](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7380041?hl=en)
- [Allow emails only with authorized addresses or domains](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2640542?hl=en)